# Turn Regular Javascript Into jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, onclick

I have some code that involves clicking on a button and either you are logged in and you go to the next page or you are logged out and you get an alert.  I have never liked `onClick` inside HTML and so I would like to turn this around into clicking on the id and having the jQuery do its magic.

I understand the click function of jQuery, but I don't know how to put `do_bid(".$val["id"].");` down with the rest of the Javascript.  If I haven't given enough information or if there is an official resource for this then let me know.

```
<li class='btn bid' onclick='do_bid(".$val["id"].");'> Bid </li>

<script>
    //Some other Javascript above this
    function do_bid(aid)
    {
        var loged_in = "<?= $_SESSION["BPLowbidAuction_LOGGED_IN"] ?>";
        if(loged_in=="")
        {
            alert('You must log in to bid!');
        }
        else
        {
            document.location.href="item.php?id="+aid;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** This is the entirety of the Javascript code. I think none of the answers have worked so far because the answers don't fit the rest of my Javascript.  I hope this helps

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
if (LeadingZero && s.length < 2)
s = "0" + s;
return "" + s + "";
}
function CountBack() {
<?
for($i=0; $i<$total_elements; $i++){
echo "myTimeArray[".$i."] = myTimeArray[".$i."] + CountStepper;";
}
for($i=0; $i<$total_elements; $i++){
echo "secs = myTimeArray[".$i."];";
echo "DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, calcage(secs,86400,1000000));";
echo "DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, calcage(secs,3600,24));";
echo "DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, calcage(secs,60,60));";
echo "DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, calcage(secs,1,60));";
echo "if(secs < 0){
if(document.getElementById('el_type_".$i."').value == '1'){
document.getElementById('el_".$i."').innerHTML = FinishMessage1;
}else{
document.getElementById('el_".$i."').innerHTML = FinishMessage2;";
echo "  }";
echo "}else{";
echo " document.getElementById('el_".$i."').innerHTML = DisplayStr;";
echo "}";
}
?>
if (CountActive) setTimeout("CountBack()", SetTimeOutPeriod);
}
function putspan(backcolor, forecolor, id) {
document.write("<span id='"+ id +"' style='background-color:" + backcolor + "; color:" + forecolor + "'></span>");
}
if (typeof(BackColor)=="undefined")     BackColor = "white";
if (typeof(ForeColor)=="undefined")     ForeColor= "black";
if (typeof(TargetDate)=="undefined")    TargetDate = "12/31/2020 5:00 AM";
if (typeof(DisplayFormat)=="undefined") DisplayFormat = "%%D%%d, %%H%%h, %%M%%m, %%S%%s.";
if (typeof(CountActive)=="undefined")   CountActive = true;
if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined") FinishMessage = "";
if (typeof(CountStepper)!="number")     CountStepper = -1;
if (typeof(LeadingZero)=="undefined")   LeadingZero = true;
CountStepper = Math.ceil(CountStepper);
if (CountStepper == 0) CountActive = false;
var SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 990;
var myTimeArray = new Array();
<?  for($i=0; $i<$total_elements; $i++){?>
ddiff=document.getElementById('el_sec_'+<?=$i;?>).value;
myTimeArray[<?=$i;?>]=Number(ddiff);
<? } ?>
CountBack();
           function do_bid(aid)
    {
        var loged_in = "<?= $_SESSION["BPLowbidAuction_LOGGED_IN"] ?>";
        if(loged_in=="")
        {
            alert('You must log in to bid!');
        }
        else
        {
            document.location.href="item.php?id="+aid;
        }
    }
}</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `class` twice, it should be `class='btn bid'`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to attach `click` event handler using jQuery. You need to first include jQuery library into your page and then try the below code.

You should not have 2 class attributes in an element. Move both btn and bid class into one class attribute.

Markup change. Here I am rendering the session variable into a data attribute to be used later inside the `click` event handler using jQuery `data` method.

PHP/HTML:

```
echo "<li class='btn bid' data-bid='".$val["id"]."'>Bid</li>";
```

JS:

```
$('.btn.bid').click(function(){
    do_bid($(this).data('bid'));
});
```

If you don't want to use data attribute and render the id into a JS variable then you can use the below code.

```
var loged_in = "<?= $_SESSION["BPLowbidAuction_LOGGED_IN"] ?>";
$('.btn.bid').click(function(){
     if(!loged_in){ 
         alert('You must log in to bid!'); 
     }
     else{
         do_bid(loged_in); 
     }
});
```

Comment: @CaryHartline - Can you tell me where is the problem? I can modify to make it work as per you.

Comment: And in the markup did you use `bid` as an id or added into the class?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make the `<li>` have the data you need to send, which I would recommend using the data attributes. For example:

```
echo "<li class=\"btn bid\" data-bid=\"{$val['id']}\">Bid</li>";
```

Next, you need to bind the click and have it call the javascript method `do_bid` which can be done using:

```
function do_bid(bid){
  //bid code
}
$(function(){
  // when you click on the LI
  $('li.btn.bid').click(function(){
    // grab the ID we're bidding on
    var bid = $(this).data('bid');
    // then call the function with the parameter
    window.do_bid(bid);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why use `window.`?  The function is global so it is accessible without that.

Comment: I tend to do it for the purpose of being explicit and so when it comes down to future modifications i know where the definition lies. It's personal preference, but I also tend to use the `this`prefix in my objects as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the id value your trying to append as a data attribute:

Something like:

```
<li class='btn' class='bid' data-id='.$val["id"].'>
```

Then bind the event like this:

```
$('.bid').click(function(){

    var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    doBid(dataId);


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have multiple of these buttons, you could use the `data` attribute to store the ID:

```
<li class='btn' class='bid' data-id='<?php echo $val["id"]; ?>'>
```

jQuery:

```
var clicked_id = $(this).data('id');     // assuming this is the element that is clicked on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Id in a `data-` attribute, then use jQuery's `.click` method.

```
<li class='btn' class='bid' data-id='".$val["id"]."'>
Bid
</li>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li.bid").click(function(){
    if ("" === "<?= $_SESSION["BPLowbidAuction_LOGGED_IN"] ?>") {
      alert('You must log in to bid!');
    }
    else {
      document.location.href="item.php?id=" + $(this).data("id");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still searching for an answer to this, I put a workaround. 
If `data` is not working for you, try the html `id`.

A working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/aVLk9/